# Cómo añadir archivo CSS/JS a la cabecera o el footer de forma correcta en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de agregar las hojas de estilos a wordpress mediante los ganchos 'wp_enqueue_scripts','wp_head' y 'wp_footer'.
Si utilizo
```
add_action("admin_head", function() use ($self,$fnamee){ 
                        $self($fnamee, false);
                    });
```
o
```
add_action("admin_footer", function () use ($sel,$fnamee){
                        $self($fnamee, true);
                    });
```
no hay ningún problema y agrega las hojas correctamente para las hojas de CSS.
Con las hojas de JS me las agrega todo el rato en footer (Esto último de los archivos JS lo intentaré solucionar por mi cuenta).
La cosa es que cuando intento agregar las hojas únicamente a las páginas que nos son de administración no me las agrega.
Quiero que únicamente carguen los estilos en sus correspondiente páginas ya que si cargan todas los archivos css/js en todas las páginas la web perdería velocidad de carga.
Tengo 2 preguntas
1: ¿ Qué gancho puedo utilizar para agregar los estilos correctamente a las hojas de la web que no son de administración?
2: ¿ Cómo puedo indicar a que páginas quiero que se apliquen los estilos css/js sin utilizar un filtro que mire las URLs para ver si es una página u otra ?
Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.
Saludos !!

Comment: Hace 20 años y en sitios muy grandes, uno se preocupaba de hacer una carga diferenciada, hoy creo que no vale la pena. Si quieres mejorar la performance de tu sitio, te recomiendo ver por qué esos css/js te están ocasionando problemas

Comment: EL problema es que no conozco los métodos que se utilizan para agregar las hojas de estilos y los javascript en el contenido.
He pedido ayuda porque lleva un tiempo intentándolo y no he conseguido que se inserten más que en las páginas de administración.
Ahora que ya he descansado un poco me voy a poner otro rato a ver si lo soluciono. De todas formas si alguien sabe como hacerlo y quiere echarme un cable bienvenido sea.
Si encuentro como hacerlo lo pondré por aquí por si a alguien le sirve.
Saludos !!

Answer (score 0):

Tras investigar un poco he descubierto que para cargar las funciones en Wordpress hay que hacerlo desde el archivo -functions.php- del tema y no desde la carpeta del plugin.
**wp_head, wp_footer, admin_head, admin_footer, login_head, login_footer** funcionan correctamente pero hay que llamar al **add_action()** desde el archivo de -functions.php- sino no funciona.
Para ello he insertado unas línea de código cuando pulso en el botón **publicar** mediante fopen, fwrite y fclose.
Espero que os sirva esta respuesta.
Saludos !!!